# Apple pay and Google pay not able to see in Magento 2 using Stripe

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, payment-gateway, stripe, googlepay

I have configured Stripe account and in that I have enabled Apple Pay and Google Pay after configuring on stripe i even enabled from Magento backend but it seems I could not see any Apple Pay and Google Pay button.

Can you please provide any solution?

Comment: Did you follow steps under “Set up Apple Pay for your website” - adding domain association file to your server?  https://support.stripe.com/questions/enable-apple-pay-on-your-stripe-account  And are you checking on supported device? Apple - Safari on iOS or MacOS only. Google Pay on Chrome Desktops or Android device only?

Comment: For Apple pay, yes I have added domain verification file as per the step given. But I couldn't see Apple pay in MacOS or IOS device. Is it something there to check Apple pay, we need to set Wallet pay in our MacOs and IOS. For google pay, what need to do to check in Chrome Desktop? Do we need to add payment method to our registered gmail account?

Comment: Yes you need a real card in your Apple wallet for it to come up. In test mode with test api keys, you real card won’t be charged https://support.stripe.com/questions/testing-apple-pay-with-stripe and for google, I think it’s the same, but not 100% sure on that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer